# Changing opportunities for roles in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, roles

I want to restrict the editor role in Google Sheets from printing and coping the table content. If I choose the role of commentator, he couldn't print and save, but also couldn't work with the table content, only commenting.
Can I create a new role with my own rules?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Nope.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on [Drive Roles](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-roles), there are only five levels of access permissions, of which only four can be given to another user:

- organiser/owner
- fileOrganiser
- writer
- commenter
- reader

You can not create your own permissions with their own rules.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

From he Drive UI at [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com) you can click the `?` icon in hte top-right and use the `Send feedback` popup to suggest this as a feature for the Drive team.

#### References:

- [Roles | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-roles)